# Auto update cart on click in WooCommerce

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to auto update the cart when quantity is changed. I got this working code in `functions.php`, but it's only working for the first click. How to adjust it so it's working for every click?

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'cart_update_qty_script' ); 
function cart_update_qty_script() { 
    if (is_cart()) : 
    ?> 
    <script> 
        jQuery('div.woocommerce').on('click', '.quantity .button', function(){ 
            jQuery("[name='update_cart']").trigger("click"); }); 
    </script> 
    <?php 
    endif; 
}
```

Comment: use this plugin as well :https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-ajax-cart/

Answer (score 3):

try it like this..

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'cart_update_qty_script' ); 
function cart_update_qty_script() { 
    if (is_cart()) : 
    ?> 
    <script>
    jQuery( 'div.woocommerce' ).on( 'change', '.qty', function () {
    jQuery( "[name='update_cart']" ).trigger( "click" );
    } );
    </script>
    <?php 
    endif; 
}
```

I it's because the html is being replaced, div.woocommerce click event is no longer there... if you attached it to body, it might work...

Comment: unfortunately same problem, but thanks for telling why this happens

Comment: I've tried the code and it's working on my end. Do you have a link we can check? or see browser's console if there's an error when you click

Comment: I am trying on staging website (pw-protected). But you can see the problem on ergotopia.de. The problem there is, only every 2nd click is firing the auto update. Function was:

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'cart_update_qty_script' );
function cart_update_qty_script() {
    if (is_cart()) :
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery('div.woocommerce').on('change', '.qty', function(){
            jQuery("[name='update_cart']").trigger("click"); 
        });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}

Comment: @KrystianManthey yes, you are right. Proper event is `change` not `click`. I have update code with version working for me in Nov 2019.

Comment: In my case only every second change triggered the Update click. It is because once the cart reloads with Ajax, the update button becomes 'disabled' and the click has no effect, until you change the quantity again. I fixed it by replacing the trigger line with this: `jQuery( "[name='update_cart']" ).prop('disabled', false).trigger( "click" );`

Answer (score 2):

The reason that is happening is because your dom is refreshed with the Ajax and events are flushed.

What you need to do is listen to the event 'updated_cart_totals' which will tell you that dom is updated and after that reactivate your listeners.

```
function quantity_upd() {
  $(".woocommerce-cart-form").on("change", ".qty", function() {
    $("[name='update_cart']").removeAttr('disabled');
    $("[name='update_cart']").trigger("click");
  });
}

$( document ).on( 'updated_cart_totals', function() {
  quantity_upd();
}
```

Please adjust it for your theme and HTML, it can vary

Answer (score 1):

The reason it only works on the first click is because everytime you update the form, it refreshes itself. So instead of doing:

```
jQuery('div.woocommerce').on('click', '.quantity .button', function() {
```

You need to switch `div.woocommerce` to `document`:

```
jQuery('document').on('click', '.quantity .button', function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use plugin like below.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-update-cart-on-quantity-change/

Also this plugin is working for you.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-ajax-cart/

Please use plugin for your safe side because plugin works in every wordpress version and woocommerce version.

OR

You can try custom code with minor modifications like below.

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'cart_update_qty_script' );
function cart_update_qty_script() {
    if (is_cart()) :
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).on("click", "div.woocommerce .quantity .button", function(e) {
               jQuery("[name='update_cart']").trigger("click"); 
            });

OR  
            jQuery("body").on("click", "div.woocommerce .quantity .button", function(e) {
                jQuery("[name='update_cart']").trigger("click"); 
            });
        </script>
        <?php
    endif;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I wont use not well supported plugins with bad ratings.

Your code is working for the 2nd click only. Then nothing more happens.

Comment: @KrystianManthey Please check my edited answer. Try it and let me know.

Comment: both version updates on first click, but then clicks are not possible anymore (quantity doesnt change).

Answer (score 0):

As I don't know your HTML structure so I built a sample jQuery which is working on storefront theme.

Here is a sample code.

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'cart_update_qty_script' );
function cart_update_qty_script() {
    if (is_cart()) :
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery('div.woocommerce').on('keyup', '.quantity .qty', function(){
            //console.log('clicked');
            jQuery("[name='update_cart']").trigger("click"); });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

Comment: maybe its because we have the newest woocommerce, wordpress etc.
With this code, nothing updates. But thank you for trying to help!

Comment: I have tested in Woo `Version 3.1.1` and WP `Version 4.8.1`. can you share your website URL?

Comment: I am trying on staging website (pw-protected). But you can see a similar problem on ergotopia.de. The problem there is, only every 2nd click is firing the auto update. Function was: add_action( 'wp_footer', 'cart_update_qty_script' ); function cart_update_qty_script() { if (is_cart()) : ?> <script> jQuery('div.woocommerce').on('change', '.qty', function(){ jQuery("[name='update_cart']").trigger("click"); }); </script> <?php endif; }

Answer (score 0):

Rather than try to trigger the click, how about removing the "disabled" attribute from the Update Cart button so the user can click it. The cart page already works this way where when the quantity is changed on an item, the Update Cart button becomes clickable.

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'cart_update_qty_script' ); 
function cart_update_qty_script() { 
    if (is_cart()) : 
    ?> 
    <script> 
        jQuery('body').on('click', 'div.woocommerce .quantity .button', function(){ 
            jQuery("[name='update_cart']").prop("disabled", false);
        }); 
    </script> 
    <?php 
    endif; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The update button is actually disabled when the page loads, so you need basically to enable it, right before triggering the click event.

Use this code:

```js
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'cart_update_qty_script' );
function cart_update_qty_script() {
  if (is_cart()) :
   ?>
    <script>
        jQuery('div.woocommerce').on('change', '.qty', function(){
           jQuery("[name='update_cart']").removeAttr('disabled');
           jQuery("[name='update_cart']").trigger("click"); 
        });
   </script>
<?php
endif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy this code to functions:

```
function bbloomer_cart_refresh_update_qty() { 
   if (is_cart()) { 
      ?>      
      <script>
        jQuery('div.woocommerce').on('change', '.qty', function(){
            jQuery("[name='update_cart']").prop("disabled", false);
            jQuery("[name='update_cart']").trigger("click");
        });
        </script>
      <?php 
   } 
}
```

End this to style:

```
button[name='update_cart'] {
display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery( function( $ ) {
 let timeout;
 $('.woocommerce').on( 'change', 'input.qty', function(){
  if ( timeout !== undefined ) {
   clearTimeout( timeout );
  }
  timeout = setTimeout(function() {
   $("[name='update_cart']").trigger("click"); 
  }, 500 ); 
 });
} );
```

Using javascript we can place this in code snippet.  and whenever add products or increase product value it's updated automatically in cart page

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).